# Recorrer CSV y quedarme con URL de imágenes

Tags: php, html, csv

Estoy tratando de recorrer un CSV con PHP, ya lo he hecho, pero ahora necesito quedarme con las URL de las imágenes, ya que son de un catálogo de un distribuidor y así poder subirlas a woocommerce.

El caso es que no consigo la manera de encontrar dentro de un array, que he creado para guardar toda la info del CSV, la ruta de la imagen, he usado algunas funciones de PHP pero sin resultado. Adjunto código e imagen de lo que necesito.

1ª imagen CSV y rutas: [image: CSV y rutas .img]

Tengo un formulario en HTML que me permite seleccionar el CSV para tratarlo y me interesa hacerlo de manera genérica porque este script se podrá usar en más situaciones.

Mi script php actual está así:

```
<?php

$fila = 1;
$array = array();
$buscar = 'https://';
$resultadoBusqueda;

if (($gestor = fopen("Productos-Euromoto-20-09-2018.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    while (($datos = fgetcsv($gestor, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $numero = count($datos);
        echo "<p> $numero de campos en la línea $fila: <br /></p>\n";
        $fila++;
        for ($i=0; $i < $numero; $i++) {
            //echo $datos[$i] . "<br />\n";
            $array = $datos[$i];
            echo 'contenido array: ' . $array;
            echo "<br>";

            //echo 'foto: ' . strstr($array[$i], 'https://', true);
        }

    }

    $resultadoBusqueda = array_filter($array, function($var) use ($buscar) { return stristr($var, $buscar) } );
        if($resultadoBusqueda){
            echo 'se ha encontrado el termino "' . $buscar .'" en la posicion <br>';
            foreach($resultados as $resultadoBusqueda){
                echo $resultados . "<br>";
            }
        }else{
            echo 'El termino "' . $buscar . '" no se ha encontrado en el array ';
        }

}
```

Pero me devuelve que falta un argumento. De todas formas, no se si será la mejor manera de hacer esto. Yo lo que necesito es que, dentro del array buscar el string que comienza por "http://" y termina en ".jpg"

Agradezco toda ayuda.

Un saludo

Comment: Procura incluir el fragmento de la traza de error, no sólo mencionar "me devuelve que falta un argumento".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de encontrar el campo que contenga 'https://' es, así:

- Cojes la línea y la combiertes en un array con `explode`.
- Recorres el array recién creado y buscas la cadena que te interesa, con un `IF`.

  ```
  $fila = 1;
  $array = array();
  $buscar = 'https://';
  $resultadoBusqueda;

  if (($gestor = fopen("a.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

      while (($datos = fgetcsv($gestor, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
          $numero = count($datos);
          echo "<p> $numero de campos en la línea $fila: <br /></p>\n";
          $fila++;
          for ($i=0; $i < $numero; $i++) {
              echo $datos[$i] . "<br />\n";
              $array = $datos[$i];
              $campos = explode(';',$array);
              foreach($campos as $campo) {
                echo "<br />".$campo;
                if( strpos($campo, $buscar) !== false){
                  echo "<br /> <b>Encontrado : </b>".$campo;
                }
              }
          }

      }

  }
  ?>
  ```

---

## Otra forma puede ser ...

Conociendo la posición del campo que contiene las imágenes también se puede hacer así...

- Conviertes la línea que es un `string` en un `array` con `explode`.
- Recorres el array con `foreach`.
- Utilizas el condicional `IF` para filtrar la posición.

*Suponiendo que el campo en la posición 11 (si es una array será el 10)...*

```
<?php

$fila = 1;
$array = array();
$buscar = 'https://';
$resultadoBusqueda;

if (($gestor = fopen("a.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    while (($datos = fgetcsv($gestor, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $numero = count($datos);
        echo "<p> $numero de campos en la línea $fila: <br /></p>\n";
        $fila++;
        for ($i=1; $i < $numero; $i++) {
            echo $datos[$i] . "<br />\n";
            $array = $datos[$i];
            $campos = explode(';',$array);
            foreach($campos as $index=>$campo) {
              echo "<br />".$campo;
             if($index == 10 && $campo != ''){
               echo "<br /> <b>Encontrado : </b>".$campo;
             }
            }
        }

    }

}
?>
```

*Espero que te sirva.*

Answer (score 2):

Al usar

```
$gestor = fopen("a.csv", "r"))
```

y luego en cada bucle:

```
fgetcsv($gestor, 1000, ","))
```

lo que obtienes de éste último es un array en donde los campos ya vienen separados, no necesitarías explotar. [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fgetcsv.php) devuelve un array de por sí:

> getcsv — Obtiene una línea de un puntero a un fichero y la analiza en
>   busca de campos CSV
>
> Descripción
>
> ```
> fgetcsv ( 
>    resource $handle 
>    [, int $length = 0 
>      [, string $delimiter = "," 
>        [, string $enclosure = '"' 
>          [, string $escape = "\"]
>        ]
>      ]
>    ]) : array
> ```
>
> Similar a fgets() excepto que fgetcsv() analiza la línea que lee para buscar campos en formato CSV, **devolviendo un array** que contiene los campos leídos.

Lo malo es que en tu tercer parámetro le estás diciendo que tu CSV está separado por comas, **pero según se ve en la foto viene separado por punto y coma**, así que debes usar punto y coma como tercer parámetro y no coma, como tienes en ese momento:

```
fgetcsv($gestor, 1000, ";"))
```

Suponiendo que tu CSV tuviese la forma:

```
"Corona 69 dientes rectos";"https://imagenes.sitio.com/corona.jpg";  "01008105"
"Embrague Reforzado";"https://imagenes.sitio.com/embrague.jpg";"01008115"
"Discos Embrague;"https://imagenes.sitio.com/discos.jpg";"01008121"
"Piñon diente helicoidal";"https://imagenes.sitio.com/helicoidal.jpg";"01008105E"
```

Tu procedimiento equivale a iterar sobre un array que se ve como:

```
$miArray = [
  ["Corona 69 dientes rectos",  "https://imagenes.sitio.com/corona.jpg",  "01008105"],
  ["Embrague Reforzado",  "https://imagenes.sitio.com/embrague.jpg",  "01008115"],
  ["Discos Embrague", "https://imagenes.sitio.com/discos.jpg", "01008121"],
  ["Piñon diente helicoidal",  "https://imagenes.sitio.com/helicoidal.jpg",  "01008105E"]
];
```

(claro que fgetcsv va a ir sacando una fila a la vez, cosa de no alojar todo en memoria)

Para efectos del ejemplo, tu iteración sería como hacer:

```
foreach( $miArray as $fila => $registro ){
    echo sprintf("La fila %d tiene %d campos %s", $fila, count($registro), PHP_EOL);
}
```

(sprintf me evita interpolar variables feas)

Para ir sacando las imágenes usas una expresión regular que dice:

> del siguiente array, dame los elementos (indexados por su posición) que empiezan con `https` y terminan en `.jpg`

Esto es:

```
foreach( $miArray as $fila => $registro ){

    echo sprintf(PHP_EOL."La fila %d tiene %d campos ".PHP_EOL,$fila,count($registro));

    $campos_con_imagen = preg_grep('/^https:\/\/.*\.jpg$/i', $registro );

    foreach($campos_con_imagen as $key => $value) {

        echo sprintf("Se encontró la imagen '%s' en el campo %d de la fila %d ".PHP_EOL, $value, $key, $fila);

    }

}
```

Eso imprime

```
La fila 0 tiene 3 campos 
Se encontró la imagen 'https://imagenes.sitio.com/corona.jpg' en el campo 1 de la fila 0 

La fila 1 tiene 3 campos 
Se encontró la imagen 'https://imagenes.sitio.com/embrague.jpg' en el campo 1 de la fila 1 

La fila 2 tiene 3 campos 
Se encontró la imagen 'https://imagenes.sitio.com/discos.jpg' en el campo 1 de la fila 2 

La fila 3 tiene 3 campos 
Se encontró la imagen 'https://imagenes.sitio.com/helicoidal.jpg' en el campo 1 de la fila 3
```

En cada iteración puedes ir metiendo las imagenes a un array y de ello obtener un listado de tuplas SKU => imagen:

```
<?php
$tuplas = [];

$miArray = [...];

foreach( $miArray as $fila => $registro ){

  $campos_con_imagen = preg_grep('/^https:\/\/.*\.jpg$/i', $registro );

  foreach($campos_con_imagen as $key => $value) {
       $tuplas[$registro[2]] = $value; // $registro[2] es el SKU o código de la pieza
   }

}

echo "Resultado final ".PHP_EOL;
print_r($tuplas);
```

Y eso imprime:

```
Resultado final 
Array
(
    [01008105] => https://imagenes.sitio.com/corona.jpg
    [01008115] => https://imagenes.sitio.com/embrague.jpg
    [01008121] => https://imagenes.sitio.com/discos.jpg
    [01008105E] => https://imagenes.sitio.com/helicoidal.jpg
)
```

[EJEMPLO COMPLETO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f6a17c862292f411ebd11647efbcb2480ac7d509)